# Is it safe and pythonic to consume the iterator in the body of a for loop?

Tags: python

Is it safe in Python to do something like this (say, in a parser)?

```
iterator = iter(some_iterable)
for x in iterator:
    # do stuff with x
    if some_condition(x):
        y = next(iterator)
        # do stuff with y
```

I've tested in Python 2 and 3 and it does what I expect, but I wonder whether it's really safe and whether it's idiomatic. The above code should be equivalent to the following rather more verbose alternative:

```
iterator = iter(some_iterable)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # do stuff with x
    if some_condition(x):
        y = next(iterator)
        # do stuff with y
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. Depending on the actual situation, it may be the best thing to do.

Comment: It does not go well with `enumerate`, but that's obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's always better to keep track of your exceptions and handle them properly. But regarding the difference between the `while` and `for` loops in this case when you are calling a `next()` function within a `while` loop it's always possible to raise an StopIteration exception, but when you are using a `for` loop based on the number of `next()` calls and your iteration it may be different.

For example in this case for even number of iteration it doesn't raise an exception but for odds it does. And the reason is that in even iteration numbers your next is always one item in front of the for loop, while for odds it's not like so.

```
In [1]: it = iter(range(4))

In [2]: for x in it:
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:     next(it)
   ...:     
0
2

In [3]: it = iter(range(3))

In [4]: for x in it:
            print(x)
            next(it)
   ...:     
0
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1b3db7079e29> in <module>()
      1 for x in it:
      2             print(x)
----> 3             next(it)
      4 

StopIteration:
```

Comment: Did you not notice that the in-loop consumption is conditional in my example? Imagine that the code is a parser for some bytecode language where some (but not all) bytecodes are followed by an argument byte. The second consumption isn't wrapped in a try/except because we assume that bytecodes that require an argument byte will in fact have one.

Comment: So in this case you should handle the exception. And I don't see any downwise for this.

Comment: @alex you should still handle the exception, it could be that the source is malformed, and that the stop iteration is swallowed by something else (this is a bigger problem in python 2, where a generator is allowed to throw a stop iteration). At the very least you catch the exception and reraise it as a new exception eg. `raise ValueError('malformed input')`